# first parameter in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning Express on Node and am running a simple server script that should return your name if it is fed as a variable, but I'm not sure how to call the variable in the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/:$jon
http://localhost:3000/?jon
http://localhost:3000/$jon
http://localhost:3000/:$jon
http://localhost:3000/:([\$])$jon
```

I really thought it was just..

```
http://localhost:3000/jon
```

The only 2 files in the directory are the server.js

```
// Load the 'express' module
const express = require('express');

// Create a new Express application instance
const app = express();

// Create a new 'hasName' middleware function
const hasName = function(req, res, next) {
    // Use the QueryString 'name' parameter to decide on a proper response
    if (req.param('name')) {
        // If a 'name' parameter exists it will call the next middleware
        next();
    } else {
        // If a 'name' parameter does not exists it will return a proper response 
        res.send('What is you name?');
    }
};

// Create a new 'sayHello' middleware function
const sayHello = function(req, res, next) {
    // Use the 'response' object to send a respone with the 'name' parameter 
    res.send('Hello ' + req.param('name'));
};

// Mount both middleware funcitons
app.get('/', hasName, sayHello);

// Use the Express application instance to listen to the '3000' port
app.listen(3000);

// Log the server status to the console
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');

// Use the module.exports property to expose our Express application instance for external usage
module.exports = app;
```

and then a package.json to include express

```
{
    "name": "MEAN",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.14.0"
    }
}
```

I'm running `nmp install` to intall the express from the dependencies and then `node server` and then getting what I'd expect at localhost

[image]

but I also just noticed I've got a depreciation on line 10.. so am I calling it wrong or do I need to patch this file? It's from a fairly recent book.

[image: params deprecated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `req.params.name` instead

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

you could write your code this way:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.send("what's your name?");
});

app.get('/:name', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('Hello ' + req.params.name);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Comment: That seems to have bypassed the deprecation error.. but I'm still not sure if i'm adding a name correctly. https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/21077415_10207806967972077_224993839926317505_n.jpg?oh=bc5222d94dba25a9da6f1aaf97722473&oe=5A2AD40B

Comment: I saw the video you posted, And what i meant is `req.param.('name')` is deprecated and instead you should use `req.params.name` but you used `req.params('name')`. Also what i am suggesting in the code above is to use 2 handlers, one for the home page '/' and the other one is for the param '/whatever'. That way you don't have to check if the url has a param or not.

Comment: Also the ':' in the '/:name' handler is to make it a parameter instead of a fixed URL, but when you access the URL you don't type the ':'

Answer (score 1):

You can just use  `app.get('/:name', hasName, sayHello);` instead of `app.get('/', hasName, sayHello);`.

Comment: I have tried both your's and M. Sallam's suggestions, but there is still something I seem to be missing. https://youtu.be/YxlwDx_N0xc

Comment: @Turtle Wolf I watched your video . Sorry for that I didn't notice the warnig you metioned as screenshot. your looking sooo confused. Copy the server code you provide and just change req.param(name) to req.params.name .It is located in two places line number 10 & line number 22 . Next change the app.get() as I answered. Run the server .And in browser check it with http://localhost:3000/Turtle . Hope this helps and it clears your doubt.